# Find sum of 2nd highest number in each row & column

Tags: java, arrays

Each element in the 2D array is considered to be a chocolate. I need to pick the max number of chocolates except the max chocolates of each row and each column. I made a program and but it is not producing the correct result for the below mentioned example.

```
1 4 0 5 2 | 4
2 1 2 0 1 | 1
0 2 3 4 4 | 3
0 3 0 3 1 | 1
1 2 2 1 1 | 1
```

Columns: `1+3+2+4+2=12`

Rows: `4+1+3+1+1=10`

Total: `12+10=22`

The output should be 22 but my output for the below attached program is 20.

```
public int calc(int[][] grid, int rows, int columns){

    int[][] check = new int[rows][columns];

    int max, pos;

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        max = grid[i][0];
        pos = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
            if(grid[i][j] >= max){
                max = grid[i][j];
                pos = j;
            }
        }
        check[i][pos] = 1;
    }

    for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
        max = grid[0][j];
        pos = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            if(grid[i][j] >= max){
                max = grid[i][j];
                pos = i;
            }
        }
        check[pos][j] = 1;
    }

    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
            if(check[i][j]!=1){
                total += grid[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugger?

Comment: @AntonHlinisty I tried debugger.

Comment: Can you explain in your question how you got to 22? What you are asking for is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is not taking into account that the `max` in a column and the `max` in a row could be the same element (or not, optionally).  For example, Row 1 has `2 1 2 0 1`.  The first `2` is the `max` of column 0, but both `2`'s are maximum values for Row 1.  Your application marks the first `2` as a column `max` in the second loop and the second `2` as a row `max` in the first loop.

Note, a similar situation exists in the second row with the value `4`, but in that case your application is only marking one of the `4`'s as a max (because you are checking against `>= max` in both loops. If you only check `> max` then the `2`'s would be correct in row 1, but your `4`'s would be messed up in row 2).

If your example is definitely supposed to return 22, then you would need to add logic to check for the intersection of `max` values on rows and columns.

Below is a brute force update that preserves most of your logic/structure.  I updated the `check` array to keep the max value found instead of just a `1`, and added an additional nested-loop which checks each row for equal `max` values.  In the last loop I updated the check for `!=1` to `==0`.

```
static public int calc(int[][] grid, int rows, int columns){

int[][] check = new int[rows][columns];

int max, pos;

for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
    max = grid[i][0];
    pos = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
        if(grid[i][j] >= max){
            max = grid[i][j];
            pos = j;
        }
    }
    check[i][pos] = max; // updated here
}

for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
    max = grid[0][j];
    pos = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        if(grid[i][j] >= max){
            max = grid[i][j];
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    check[pos][j] = max; // updated here
}

// UPDATE HERE
// these loops look for rows that have two 
// max values (one for a column and one for a row) that are equal
for(int j=0; j<rows; j++){
  max = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<columns; i++){
    if(check[j][i] != 0) {
      if (max == 0){
        max = check[j][i];
      }else if (max == check[j][i]){
        // reset
        check[j][i] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

int total = 0;
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
        if(check[i][j]==0){ // updated here
            total += grid[i][j];
        }
    }
}
return total;
}
```